# Como faço uma mascara que se adapte a inputs com preço?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu estava utilizando o JQuery mas como faço pra ele se adaptar ao colocar 2 números inserir uma ',' desse jeito mas seriam necessários colocar 4 valores, e eu não sei o preço ao certo que seria

```
$('[formato=price]').mask('9999,99');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talvez não é a solução esperada mais é o melhor a ser feito.

No seu caso eu recomendaria o uso do plugin [Jquery Maskmoney](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/), Esse pluginzinho já vem no jeito para formatar campos para dinheiro de acordo com suas necessidades, além de algumas opções bem legais. Você pode acessar a última versão desse plugin minificada clicando [aqui](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)

Ou usar via cdn incluindo no seu codigo: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>`

Solução final ficou assim:

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="ValoresItens" id="ValoresItens">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
```

> JS

```
$(".ValoresItens").maskMoney({
             prefix: "R$:",
             decimal: ",",
             thousands: "."
         });
```

> Resultado final pode ser visto em :
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu queria fazer um input para preços de itens e queria que ao colocar 2 números no input fosse inserido uma virgula simbolizando  centavos e depois seria digitado as dezenas, por exemplo no mercadolivre que creio que tenha o mesmo sistema pra colocar preço nos seus anúncios

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado pela informação, mais as vezes é difícil dar um boa resposta não tendo uma boa pergunta. Editei a resposta e melhorei ela da melhor forma possivel. caso tenha resolvido seu problema comunique.